# Build react native app to apk file after making new changes?

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

I build a react native app with this [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) , its working fine then , But when i am implementing new changes to **apk** ,  its not installing properly on my **android Mobile device** and gives error on first open ,
please help .[image: a]

Comment: are you building a debug or release apk ?

Comment: Yes i build it earliar , now i want to implement my new changes to apk  ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the new changes first bundle your js file, and then after that either you can create a debug APK whihc needs a development server or build a release apk which doesnt require.

1. in your main app directory paste this

updated:

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
>   index.js --bundle-output
>   android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
>   android/app/src/main/res

2.to build debug apk ,

go to android directory , and then `./gradlew assembleDebug`

or for release apk ,

go to android directory , and then `./gradlew assembleRelease`

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts

Comment: Actually , I am new to React-native so not able to understand Technical language , geeting confused where to paste this . Can you please elaborate ,.

Comment: okay, so the first command you will paste it in the terminal of your directory of the app, and execute it. like suppose in C:/App/YourApp in this directory in terminal you paste the command and execute it. 

After that cd android from the directory and then execute both the commands like ./gradlew assembleDebug and all

Comment: while i paste this gives an error....Loading dependency graph...error The resource `C:\Users\Dev26\Application\index.android.js` was not found. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: The resource `C:\Users\DitsDev26\Music\Application\index.android.js` was not found.
    at fs.realpath.err (C:\Users\Dev26\Application\node_modules\metro\src\IncrementalBundler.js:157:26)
    at gotStat (fs.js:1600:21)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)

Comment: is this your app name? Application?

Comment: No its just folder name

Comment: try the updated command in 1. see abovei n answer , and also in android/app/src/main/ create a folder named assets

Comment: yeah , its working  , Thanks for your answer , So what if i have to build it again , i have to follow the same steps ?

Comment: yes, gain you have to do the same thing :) , and do upvote if it helped you . thanks

Comment: Hello @Gaurav can you help me

Comment: @AnujSharma yes whats the problem

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\dines\Documents\ANUJ\ditsportal\android\app\build.gradle' line: 200

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\dines\Documents\ANUJ\ditsportal\android\app\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\dines\Documents\ANUJ\ditsportal\android\app\build.gradle': 200: expecting '}', found '' @ line 200, column 1.
  1 error
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: I am making a build of react native app but it gives this error

Comment: check build.gradle , is there any bracket missing?

Comment: I corrected it, but as I build my project with expo so now it is giving this error                                             **Unable to resolve module `expo` from `App.js`: expo could not be found within the project.**

Comment: can you post your app.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209283/discussion-between-anuj-sharma-and-gaurav-roy).

Comment: hello gavrav Can you help me ?

Answer (score -1):

I was also facing the same issues and I had tried

> cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleDebug

and It was not working for me

then I tried running at root

> yarn createDebug

and checked apk at

> root/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

It worked for me