# react-native android bundle is not loading the assets for release

Tags: react-native

I have a project running react-native 0.59.9.  I'm having problems getting the assets into the release bundle.  It runs fine in debug mode, but doesn't seem to load any images when I gradlew bundle release.  The iOS side works as expected, just having issues with Android.

I've tried updating gradle and updating react-native, but neither seems to help.  I'm not sure what to try at this point.

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0`

Comment: did you built Apk file of App

Comment: I'm building a bundle file.
`./gradlew bundleRelease`

Answer (score 0):

Paste this in your cmd

./gradlew assembleRelease

If it doesnt work , remove the " ./ " from starting..

Check here

[Build react native app to apk file after making new changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59464808/build-react-native-app-to-apk-file-after-making-new-changes/59465108#59465108)

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts

Comment: Same result, when I run the release variant there are not images.

Comment: does it helps ?

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes to solve this problem you have to put `assets` folder at the same level as `android` and `ios` folders for android release to work. Something like this:

```
|__ android
|__ assets
|__ ios 
|__ ... (my be app and other folders)
```

**Note: Don't forget to update all your reference to the new location of `assets` folder.**